# STK - Create a scanning sensor

Tags: software, sensors, stk-agi

I need a tool to create a scanning-type sensor. On STK you can only select a spinning-type sensor. I found one guy who made this sensor on STK but I don't know how.

The information below the linked video (from 2012) says the following, but there are no links provided:

> This is an example HTML Utility that can be opened inside of AGI's STK (Systems Tool Kit) which allows users to enter some defining parameters to set up a scanning sensor profile.  Selection criteria can define the overall Field of Regard of the scanning pattern, Azimuth/Elevation of the Field of Regard, Number of interior scanning rows, Field of View of the scanning sensor, Scanning Rate, and the scanning patterns (such as Top/Bottom, Bottom/Top, Left/Right, Right/Left).
>
> This utility takes these parameters from the user and creates a native STK Sensor Pointing file for the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

The video look and feel makes me think it was generated by AGI, so you could easily mail support@agi.com

The short answer, is that you cannot do it just out of the box.  You have to generate pointing data external to STK and feed it in as a .sp file.  The external data file could be generated with Matlab, python, or any other tool of your choice.  AGI has a great [example](https://agiweb.secure.force.com/faqs/articles/HowTo/How-do-I-create-a-scanning-sweeping-sensor) on their website which seems very similar to the one on the video: